# Places of interest to see while visiting Malta?

Tags: sightseeing, malta

I shall be visiting the island of Malta this summer for two weeks. Whenever I visit a country, I don't just want to lie on the beach or sit by the pool every day. I wish to get out and about to see the country and its people.

I plan on visiting the capital Valletta. I have been told the Blue Lagoon on the island of Comino is worth a visit. As I shall be staying in the north of the island, close to the ferry terminal, I also plan to visit the island of Gozo. If anyone has experience of Malta and its islands (which I am aware is very popular with British and Italian tourists, amongst other Europeans), further guidance with regards to churches, museums, palaces, town and villages with historical context (if any) that may be visited either in the capital or the rest of the island(s) would be much appreciated.

(I know that Malta, in particular its island of Gozo is famous for deep-sea diving, I won't be partaking in that).

Comment: @MarcelC. I dont know much about Malta. so I don't know how ?

Comment: @MarcelC. If the above edited question is not acceptable, I shall delete it. (Which is a shame considering there is nothing about Malta asked by other people)

Comment: @MarcelC. I don't know how to edit the question to make it more specific, thats all. Maltese questions appear to be very thin on the ground here, so surely would help other people, who may visit Malta in the future. If it doesnt end up being acceptable, I shall delete.

Comment: @Simon I think your question needs to be a little further reworking because as per [FAQ](http://travel.stackexchange.com/faq) your question is asking for an opinion related to travelling to Malta.  If you have any specific concerns please narrow it down further...

Comment: @Karlson Apart from it being a former British colony & one of the smallest nations in Europe, I dont know much about Malta, and hence the reasons for wanting to know. Apart from DJClayworth who went there 30 yrs ago, no one else seems to know anything

Comment: @Simon, yes, you may not know about Malta, but you DO have an idea of stuff you like to see, do and so on.  That's what they're trying to say when the [faq] says be more specific (it's in the [faq] if you read it).  If you can edit your question to say what sort of thing you're after (you've said you don't want to lie by the pool, but what DO you prefer doing? Museums? Tours? Drinking?) and flag to reopen, then we can get some people answering (there are people on here who have been to Malta).

Comment: Have a look at this list here: [59 Best Points of Interest and Places to Visit in Malta](https://www.maltauncovered.com/points-of-interest-places-to-visit/). Plenty of ideas to get started with.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend blue lagoon, actually. When I went, the entire place was crawling with party boats of British tourists. They were literally stepping on us, throwing garbage into the water, screaming, throwing up on the rocks. It was very difficult to find a place to lay since the beach is rocky and the outcroppings were covered in said tourists. It was insanity. But this was at the height of summer, so your mileage may vary. Stay in Valetta, for sure visit Gozo, walk around Rabat. I wouldn't bother with Sliema unless you're into going to nightclubs.

Comment: Also, there is one ferry which doesn't include unlimited alcohol on board for free. That is the best one to choose if you'd like quiet. I'd name it, but I don't want to appear to be advertising.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Malta is a place with a lot of places of historic and archeological values.  It hosts the [oldest free standing buildings in the world](http://whc.unesco.org/en/list/132) (Older than the pyramids!).  These are definitely worth a visit.  The countryside is scattered with pre-historic remains.  There are several Roman remains as well, like the [Roman Villa in Rabat](http://www.mydestination.com/malta/sights/11228/domvs-romana---roman-villa) (Domus Romana)

Other places worth seeing are:

- [Blue Grotto](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Grotto_%28Malta%29)
- [Hagar Qim megalithic temples](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C4%A6a%C4%A1ar_Qim)
- [Is-Simblija](http://www.maltain360.com/default.aspx#110022846) medieval village
- **Mdina**, the silent city and old capital of Malta
- Definitely one of the several [village festas](http://www.visitmalta.com/en/village-festas), happening every week in some town in Malta, based on dates. I would suggest checking out an [event calendars](http://www.visitmalta.com/en/search-events?pg=1&from=2013-06-01&to=2013-06-01) to find where they are happening
- [Hypogeum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypogeum_of_%C4%A6al-Saflieni) (also known as Hal-Saflieni), an underground temple in Hal-Tarxien - You need to book beforehand as entrance is very limited due to sensitivity of location.
- The cities in the Valletta area have a lot of historical context, mainly **Isla**, **Birgu** and **Bormla**.
- [Dwejra Azure Window](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azure_Window)
- The list can go on almost endlessly, based on what you like.  Given the tiny size of Malta, you've definitely got loads to see and go around!

I would suggest taking a look at [Visit Malta](http://www.visitmalta.com/) for information about Malta, and [Visit Gozo](http://www.visitgozo.com/), a recently launched portal for information about the sister island of Gozo.

Comment: To further add to this, I would definitely suggest renting a car as most of the places are in the countryside / out of the way and might not be easily accessible by bus.

Comment: Actually everything you listed here *is* accessible by bus, but not necessarily quickly or conveniently. (I'm not sure about Is-Simblija.)  I've seen most of Malta without a car, but I could see that locals very much prefer cars, and Malta tops the cars per population chart in Europe.

Comment: Note that the azure window is now no more, sadly.

Answer (score 3):

I visited Malta nearly thirty years ago so this might be out of date. Malta isn't a large island, and you aren't going to find exciting sightseeing to keep you busy for two weeks. If you have a car, everywhere is a day trip from everywhere else. The [Wikitravel page](http://wikitravel.org/en/Malta) will give more details. Most of the places to see are in Valletta, with Mdina being interesting too. You might also try Saint Paul's Bay, the traditional site where Saint Paul was shipwrecked on Malta. However there wasn't much to see when I was there.

Comment: At least you have been to Malta, which I dont think anyone else on this site has done (which is fairly surprising) I was told there is a question on this site regarding travelling to the Moon. Somehow I think tourism to Malta is far greater than to the Moon, even if not by travellers here

Comment: I don't think I'll hire a car, travel instead with the locals & tourists on the local bus network...much more fun.

Comment: Busses will take you most places and are colourful, but slow, and old. Hopefully they've bought a few new ones in the last thirty years.

Comment: The buses you are talking about & which are characteristic of Malta were abandoned a few yrs ago, for a modern fleet.